# ¿Como pasar una lista de datos como parámetro a un store procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente: Desde mi controlador .net paso una lista como parámetro(conjunto de codigo de empleado) y quiero saber como recibirlo en mi store procedure para que me devuelva una lista empleados de acuerdo al parametro pasado.

Ejemplo
tabla Empleado

```
CODIGO|NOMBRE|SALARIO
D123   JUAN    1000
D432   ROBERTO 1800
D445   ANA     1200
D182   JULIO   1500
```

STORE PROCEDURE

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CONSULTAR
    @PARAMETRO (NO SE QUE TIPO DE DATO PASAR)= D432,D445--> FILTRAR POR ESOS CODIGOS
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT CODIGO,NOMBRE,SALARIO FROM EMPLEADO
        WHERE CODIGO IN (@PARAMETRO)
    END
```

Comment: Podrías pasarlo como varchar(x), para enviar una lista separada por comas y en el SP hacer un split de los valores. Dependiendo de la versión de tu SQL podrás utilizar el Split nativo (STRING_SPLIT https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) o crearte una FDU (Función propia) que haga el split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple es crear un tipo

```
CREATE TYPE ListaDeCodigos AS TABLE (Codigo varchar(10));

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CONSULTAR
@PARAMETRO ListaDeCodigos
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CODIGO,NOMBRE,SALARIO FROM EMPLEADO
    WHERE CODIGO IN (@PARAMETRO)
END
```

Antes de llamar al procedimiento, deberás hacer

```
DECLARE @lista ListaDeCodigos;
INSERT @lista VALUES ('D432'),('D445')
```

Luego llamas al procedimiento

```
EXEC dbo.SP_CONSULTAR @lista;
```

Answer (score 0):

Del lado de C# puedes agregar lo siguiente en el llamado de tu SP

//parametro lista

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connstring))

{

    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec SP_CONSULTAR @parametro", con))

    {

        using (var table = new DataTable()) {

          table.Columns.Add("Codigos", typeof(string));

            table.Rows.Add("D123");
              table.Rows.Add("D432");

            var pList = new SqlParameter("@parametro", SqlDbType.Structured);

          pList.TypeName = "dbo.ListaDeCodigos";

          pList.Value = table;

          cmd.Parameters.Add(pList);

          using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())

          {

            while (dr.Read())
                { //aqui la lectura de resultados.
}


          }

         }

    }

}
```